# Pandas data validation with regex on one column

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

What I want to do is look for a specific pattern. 1 letter, a dash, followed by a year and letter like "A-2012A". After that, the rest of the column's value can be anything. I want to confirm this first part. And return a true/false value. Is it possible?

pattern `letter-yearletter`

String validation on one column with regular expression.

`example_column_1`

| DNA \ Assay |
| --- |
| A-2000X-27 |
| A-2000X-32 |
| A-2000X-45 |
| A-2000X-48 |
| A-2000X-80 |

```
truth_value = df['DNA \ Assay'].str.match(r'').astype(bool)
```

Sample, with nothing in the `r''` regular expression.

My expected output would be `True`

`example_column_2`

| DNA \ Assay |
| --- |
| Embryo FTA-Code-ID-2 |
| Embryo FTA-Code-ID-3 |
| Embryo FTA-Code-ID-4 |
| Embryo FTA-Code-ID-5 |
| Embryo FTA-Code-ID-6 |

My expected output with `example_column_2` would be `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
df['valid'] = df['DNA \\ Assay'].str.match(r'[A-Z]-\d{4}[A-Z]', case=False)
```

output:

```
  DNA \ Assay  valid
0  A-2000X-27   True
1  A-2000X-32   True
2  A-2000X-45   True
3  A-2000X-48   True
4  A-2000X-80   True
```

If you want to validate `all` values:

```
df['DNA \\ Assay'].str.match(r'[A-Z]-\d{4}[A-Z]', case=False).all()
```

output: `True`